# PHP MYSQL simplest user search technique with sorted results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user table in mysql with cols : `user_id`,`first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name` I want a query that would return me `user_id`list sorted in the order of closest match.

E.G. If i search John f kenedy or f john kenedy or kenedy f john and so on , would return same set of results sorted similarly as : john f kenedy as first , john kenedy(a different user) as second, john kent as third , so on....

my server script is php so a simple & efficient php algorithm would be acceptable, but it should be quick as it would be the source for hint to iser while typing in the text box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is count the number of fields that match your query and order by that:

```
order by (@QUERY like concat('%', first_name, '%') +
          @QUERY like concat('%', middle_name, '%') +
          @QUERY like concat('%', last_name, '%')
         ) desc
```

However, this is a rather expensive operation that indexes cannot improve.

If you are doing this type of searching, you are best learning about the full text search capabilities in MySQL (start [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)).